# How can I run com.apple.tools.info-plist-utility?

Tags: xcode, build, plist, utility

I am using XCode to build an iPhone application, where I would like to externally process the info plist file in the same manner as the XCode build step shown below does

```
Processing /Users/kte/Projects/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestAppGen.app/Info.plist TestAppGen-Info.plist
mkdir /Users/kte/Projects/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestAppGen.app
cd /Users/kte/Projects/TestAppGen
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
<com.apple.tools.info-plist-utility> TestAppGen-Info.plist -genpkginfo /Users/kte/Projects/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestAppGen.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format xml -o /Users/kte/Projects/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestAppGen.app/Info.plist
```

This excerpt from the build log refers to a com.apple.tools.info-plist-utility, which I gather from various sources around the net, is an internal XCode utility.

Is it possible to run the com.apple.tools.info-plist-utility from a command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tool called PlistBuddy, `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`, have a look at its man page.

But you will also need to convert the plist back to a binary plist file. This can be done like this in a build script

```
plutil -convert binary1 "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
```

Answer (score 2):

The "plutil" answer is a great start.  Unfortunately the Xcode build process does more to the Info.plist file than converting it to binary, for example on my system it adds in the fields:

-MinimumOSVersion
-PlatformName
-CFBundleExecutable
-SDKName
-CFBundleResourceSpecification
-CFBundleSupportedPlatforms

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW1) you aren't supposed to set up some of these values yourself:

> MinimumOSVersion
>
> MinimumOSVersion (String). When you
>   build an iPhone application, Xcode
>   notes the target OS (as determined by
>   the Base SDK selection) as the
>   MinimimOSVersion property. Do not
>   specify this property yourself in the
>   Info.plist file; it is a
>   system-written property. When you
>   publish your application to the App
>   Store, the store indicates the iPhone
>   OS release on which your application
>   can run based on this property. It is
>   equivalent to the
>   LSMinimumSystemVersion property on Mac
>   OS X.

I'm running into all sorts of problems trying to re-sign my application as part of my custom build process.